# Lower convex hull

Tags: python, scipy, convex-hull

At the moment I am implementing an algorithm to compute the [Newton-Polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_polygon) in Python.

In Scipy there is already a function to compute the convex hull of a given set of points, but I am not understanding how to take its lower boundary, does someone have an idea?

I already applied the `ConvexHull` function from Scipy and tried only taking the first few entries up until the point on the right, but it sometimes it resulted in the upper convex hull.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your current post does not contain any code, so we cannot test what you have done. It is also not clear what your question is, but that may be clarified if you include the current plot and your code.

Comment: idk, maybe find leftmost and the rightmost point of the hull, and take only points below the line connecting them?

Comment: @Marat Apparently this doesn't work. See this simple example https://share.sketchpad.app/23/05e-6102-76a2d0.png

Comment: It works if you test for all lines of the convex hull, any of the other points of the convex hull lies below them... . But thats very costly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would solve this by finding the extreme x values, and getting the points between the two. SciPy is guaranteed to emit coordinates for the convex hull of a set of 2D points in counter-clockwise order, so you can read from the position of the minimum x value to the position of the maximum x value, and get the lower convex hull.

Code:

```
def get_lower(polygon):
    minx = np.argmin(polygon[:, 0])
    maxx = np.argmax(polygon[:, 0]) + 1
    if minx >= maxx:
        lower_curve = np.concatenate([polygon[minx:], polygon[:maxx]])
    else:
        lower_curve = polygon[minx:maxx]
    return lower_curve
```

Example of how to use this:

```
import scipy.spatial
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng()
points = rng.random((10, 2))
hull = scipy.spatial.ConvexHull(points)

plt.plot(points[:,0], points[:,1], 'o')
for simplex in hull.simplices:
    plt.plot(points[simplex, 0], points[simplex, 1], 'k-')

lower_curve = get_lower(points[hull.vertices])
plt.plot(lower_curve[:, 0], lower_curve[:, 1])
```